# IE duplicates my div and displays it below the orginal. I have no idea why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div that has two buttons in it that has a jQuery function. Beneath this IE displays that same div with none of the content seemingly without reason. Here's the URL: http://ht.io-web.com/home-%281%29. Again its only in IE this happens, if you want to see whats its supposed to look like look in Crome or Firefox. Thanks for the help. Here's the code as well:

```
<div class="home-upper">
<h1>
Language Learning. <span>Simplified.</span></h1>
<div class="signup">
<div class="buttons">
    <span class="shaded"><a href="javascript:tgT()"><span class="green-button huge">Find Tutors</span></a></span><span class="shaded"> <img src="/HireaTutor/media/images/structure/or.png" class="or">&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="javascript:tgS()"><span class="SignUpGreen huge">Sign Up </span></a></span></div>
<div class="sign-up white" style="display: block;">

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="clear:both;padding-left:12px;" class="get-started">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Full Name</td>
                    <td>
                        Email</td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox" id="fullName"></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="textbox" id="email"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript:GetStarted();"><span class="green-button">Get Started</span></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>
<div class="find-tutors white" style="display: block;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="find-tutors" style="display: table;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    I speak</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="spoken"><option>English</option><option>French</option><option>Spanish</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    and I'm learning:</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="learning"><option>English</option><option>French</option><option>Spanish</option></select></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:findTutor();"><span class="green-button">Search</span></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide the javascript code that's relevant to your problem. It's also helpful to remove any html and javascript that is not relevant. Sometimes this can even help you find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some fairly major HTML errors. Such as:

> Line 103, Column 16: ID "head" already defined
>         <div id="head">
>   An "id" is a unique identifier. Each time this attribute is used in a document it must have a different value. If you are using this attribute as a hook for style sheets it may be more appropriate to use classes (which group elements) than id (which are used to identify exactly one element).
>
> Line 3, Column 11: ID "head" first defined here
>   <head id="head">

---

> Line 158, Column 17: ID "NavMiddle" already defined
>       <li id="NavMiddle">
>
> Line 156, Column 17: ID "NavMiddle" first defined here
>   >li id="NavMiddle">

---

> Line 180, Column 23: document type does not allow element "style" here

Try fixing those, and then maybe you might start to see expected behaviour.